# My screen goes black when I lower the Brightness to minimum. How can I control it?

Tags: display, screen, brightness, hp

What I think is that the minimum value of brightness is set to zero brightness of screen. If somehow, I can manually set to to a value very less, but still more that zero, than it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above-suggested solution to edit the `/etc/acpi/asus-keyboard-backlight.sh` does not work for me, too.
I added `notify-send "hello"` in the above-mentioned shell script, but I didn't see any notification, so I assume this script is not called on increase/decrease backlight.

Anyway, after a few hours of googling the only working solution I found is using this little tool - [zero_brightness_fixer](https://github.com/nuccy/zero_brightness_fixer).
Basically it is a service that listen for brightness change and if the new value is below the one you set, it will prevent the change restoring the brightness to the minimal value you have chosen.

How to install it on Ubuntu 18.04 and derivatives:

```
sudo apt install g++
git clone https://github.com/nuccy/zero_brightness_fixer.git
cd zero_brightness_fixer
sudo mv zero_brightness_fixer /usr/local/bin/
sudo mv zero_brightness_fixer.service /etc/systemd/system/
sudo systemctl enable zero_brightness_fixer
sudo service zero_brightness_fixer start
```

Don't forget to adjust settings in zero_brightness_fixer.service (check the README for details)

Answer (score 1):

the screen turning black is not an issue to worry about. It's a mere feature by default in ubuntu which allows brightness from 0-100 unlike windows where there is a minimum value say 1 or 5 and maximum value 100.

Comment: how can I set Min Brightness Value to 1 or 5 in Ubuntu 16.10 ??

Answer (score 1):

You can infact change the minimum brightness, but not always through some value in the config file.

In `/etc/acpi/events` there are a bunch of bash files that control the behavior of keys. Use less to view the file and see where it's pointing, then edit that file.

**For example**

Mine links to `/etc/acpi/asus_keyboard-backlight.sh` and actually does     contain a MIN value of 0. I would then adjust that MIN variable to whatever I saw fit.

```
# this directory is a symlink on my machine:
KEYS_DIR=/sys/class/leds/asus\:\:kbd_backlight

test -d $KEYS_DIR || exit 0

MIN=0
MAX=$(cat $KEYS_DIR/max_brightness)
VAL=$(cat $KEYS_DIR/brightness)

if [ "$1" = down ]; then
        VAL=$((VAL-1))
else
        VAL=$((VAL+1))
fi

if [ "$VAL" -lt $MIN ]; then
    VAL=$MIN
elif [ "$VAL" -gt $MAX ]; then
        VAL=$MAX
fi

echo $VAL > $KEYS_DIR/brightness
```

Comment: I tried to change it as a root user. I changed the value to 10, 20, 25 but nothing happened, even after restart. Am I missing anything ??

Comment: sudo vim /etc/acpi/asus_keyboard-backlight.sh then just adjust the values.